# Asymptote of a Path - Regarding Interpretation and Proof.

Tags: real-analysis

I have recently been studying paths and I stumbled upon this question:

Let $f: [a, b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ be a path such that $\lim_{x\to b}\Vert{f(t)}\Vert = \infty$ and $ L = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R^2}; \alpha x + \beta y = c \}$ be a line. We write $u = (\alpha, \beta)$ and we can assume $\Vert{u}\Vert = \alpha^2 + \beta^2 = 1$. The following statements are equivalent:

(i) $\lim_{t \to b} d(f(t), L) = 0$;

(ii) $\lim_{t \to b} \langle f(t), u \rangle = c$ and $\lim_{t \to b}  \left\langle \cfrac{f(t)}{\Vert{f(t)}\Vert}, u \right\rangle  = 0$.

My question is concerned with the implication from (i) to the first part of (ii) and I'll break it into two parts:

1. The author says that the inner product in consideration is the canonical inner product in $\mathbb{R^n}$. Since this is the case, do I have to assume that the norm we are using is the one induced by the inner product given or are we working with an arbitrary norm (which, from here on, I'll be calling $\Vert{\cdot}\Vert_A$)?
2. The second is regarding the correctness of the proof. My idea worked in the following way:

- Because $L$ is a closed set, we have that $\forall t \in [a,b)\; \exists \; z_0 \in L \;$ s.t. $\: d(f(t), L) = \Vert{f(t) - z_0}\Vert_A$, where $z_0 = (x_0, y_0)$, s.t. $\alpha x_0 + \beta y_0 = c$.
- If we are using an arbitrary norm then $\exists \; a > 0$ s.t. $ \Vert{x}\Vert_M \leq a\Vert{x}\Vert_A \; \forall x \in \mathbb{R^2}$, where $\Vert{\cdot}\Vert_M$ correspondes to the max norm.
- Finally, because $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 = 1$, this implies that $\vert{\alpha}\vert + \vert{\beta}\vert > 0$.

Now, we take an arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$. Given that condition (i) holds then:
$$
\exists \; \delta > 0 \; ; \; \forall \; t \in [a, b), \; \vert{t - b}\vert < \delta \; \Rightarrow \; d(f(t), L) < \cfrac{\varepsilon}{(\vert{\alpha}\vert + \vert{\beta}\vert) a}.
$$

The first point implies that
$$
\quad \Vert{f(t) - z_0}\Vert_A < \cfrac{\varepsilon}{(\vert{\alpha}\vert + \vert{\beta}\vert) a}.$$

We multiply everything by the positive number $a$, and we get
$$
\Vert{f(t) - z_0}\Vert_M \leq a\Vert{f(t) - z_0}\Vert_A < \cfrac{\varepsilon}{(\vert{\alpha}\vert + \vert{\beta}\vert) }.
$$

This last inequality implies two things:
$$
\vert{f_1(t) - x_0}\vert < \cfrac{\varepsilon}{(\vert{\alpha}\vert + \vert{\beta}\vert) } \;  \quad
$$
and
$$
\vert{f_2(t) - y_0}\vert < \cfrac{\varepsilon}{(\vert{\alpha}\vert + \vert{\beta}\vert)}$$
for every $t \in [a,b)$ (where $f_1(t)$ and $f_2(t)$ are the coordinate functions of $f$).

Multiplying the first inequality by $\vert{\alpha}\vert$, the second one by $\vert{\beta}\vert$ and using the triangle inequality we get:
$$
\vert{\alpha f_1(t) + \beta f_2(t) - (\alpha x_0 + \beta y_0)}\vert < \varepsilon \Rightarrow \vert{\langle f(t), u \rangle - c}\vert < \varepsilon .
$$

This means: $ \; \lim_{t \to b} \langle f(t), u \rangle = c$.

P.S.: Maybe I went a little too overboard with the explanation. This is my first ever post, so if it is too much I apologize. The question was taken from "Curso de Análise Vol. 2" by Elon Langes Lima.